# How can i remove regular strings from a search key?

Tags: mysql

I want to remove some special strings like ' in, at, on, a, an ,with... etc' from a search string in MySql.
    eg-
     `select * from tbl_search where serachkey='best hotels in kerala';`

I need to remove 'in' from string and need to look on database for best match, its somthing like google search.

I have one table with id,keys and parent_id.

The most scored parent_id should emit first.

Comment: **`String str='...'`** is not valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: @spencer 
`select * from tbl_search where serachkey='best hotels in kerala';`
is the sql query.

Comment: So, is this the query you want to run: `select * from tbl_search where serachkey='best hotels kerala'`? Will that return the rows you want? What about `'kerala best hotels'`?

Comment: @spencer Actually the searchkeys store may be like 'best,kearla,hotel,room'  like this.Each key may be as separate row. But i need to list paraent_id with maximum matches. search key may be 'best hotels in kerala'  or 'kerala best hotels' like that .

Comment: To remove strings from a comma separated list in MySQL, you could do something ugly like this: `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(','terms',') ,',in,',',') ,',at,',',') ,',on,',',') ,',a,',',')`.  But I don't think "removing strings" helps gets you closer to a design for the actual problem you are trying to solve. MySQL does provide a Full-Text search function. (But that uses a "stop word" list; that causes words to omitted from searches, there's no need for another function to remove those words from strings.)

Comment: @spencer: thanks for your information about fulltext search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Search is not an easy task to build.. but What you are in need of is Natural Language Processing.

Learn about `OPEN NLP` or `Stanford NLP`.

This will identify the parts of speech in a given sentence and you can manipulate further as per your needs.

You can also train a model for your needs.

[Link for OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/)

Comment: Iam looking for a solution in MySql.
How it possible with MySql by using maximum features of MySql.